# Artifactory Remote P2 Repository functionality doesn't cached all children location

Tags: artifactory, p2

I 'd like to use Artifactory Pro (version 4.14) as a proxy for several an external P2 repository. My idea is that all request in our Maven Tycho build go over Artifactory's proxy P2 repository.

Therefore, I create a remote P2 repository for the URL  `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/` in Artifactory and configure this P2 repository in my Maven Tycho build (whole configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/sparsick/target-definition-dsl-example/tree/artifactory-p2-bug-example)).  Unfortunalty, my build fails because of `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` (whole error log , see below ).

My investigsation reveals that the original P2 repository is a composite P2 repository and one of its children has `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/` as location URL (you can find the children locations in the `compositeContent.xml`). Maven Tycho tries to connect this child location, directly.  My expectation is that Artifactory would replace this URL by internal cached variant, so that the client doesn't go directly to the remote child url (like for example Sonatype Nexus does it).

Is this only configuration issue? If this is so, where I can configure it in Artifactory?

Whole error log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building target-definition-dsl-example 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ target-definition-dsl-example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-eclipserun-plugin:0.25.0:eclipse-run (default) @ target-definition-dsl-example ---
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/org.eclipse.updates.mars.201602261000/ (142B)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/org.eclipse.updates.mars.201602261000/ (142B)
[INFO] Adding repository http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/org.eclipse.updates.mars.201602261000
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/ (128B)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/ (128B)
[INFO] Adding repository http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/2.0/ (128B)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/2.0/ (128B)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/2.1/ (128B)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/obeo-releng-tools-releases/2.1/ (128B)
[INFO] Expected eclipse log file: C:\Users\10520312\workspace\target-definition-dsl-example\target\eclipserun-work\data\.metadata\.log
[INFO] Command line:
        [C:\devel\Java\jdk1.8.0_72_x64\jre\bin\java.exe, -jar, C:\Users\10520312\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.3.100.v20150511-1540\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar, -install, C:\Users\10520312\workspace\target-definition-dsl-example\target\eclipserun-work, -configuration, C:\Users\10520312\workspace\target-definition-dsl-example\target\eclipserun-work\configuration, -consoleLog, -application, fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.targetPlatform.converter, eclipse-mars.tpd]
>>  Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/eclipse-mars-releases/ (0B of 128B at 0B/s)
>>  Fetching p2.index from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/eclipse-mars-releases/ (128B of 128B at 0B/s)
>>  1 operation remaining.
>>  Fetching compositeContent.jar from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/eclipse-mars-releases/ (0B of 502B at 0B/s)
>>  1 operation remaining.
>>  Fetching compositeContent.jar from http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/eclipse-mars-releases/ (502B of 502B at 0B/s)
!SESSION 2017-01-16 09:31:30.389 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -application fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.targetPlatform.converter eclipse-mars.tpd
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog -application fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.targetPlatform.converter eclipse-mars.tpd

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2017-01-16 09:31:56.049
!MESSAGE Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/p2.index failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.doValidateContents(Diagnostician.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:161)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.doValidateContents(Diagnostician.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:161)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:108)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter.doGenerateTargetDefinitionFile(Converter.java:106)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter.generateTargetDefinitionFile(Converter.java:74)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.ConverterApplication.start(ConverterApplication.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2017-01-16 10:03:56.928
        !MESSAGE Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/content.xml
        !STACK 0
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
        !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2017-01-16 10:04:18.107
        !MESSAGE Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/p2.index failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
        !STACK 0
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
        !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2017-01-16 10:05:21.362
        !MESSAGE Provisioning exception
        !STACK 1
        org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/content.xml
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.validation.TargetPlatformValidator.checkIUIDAndRangeInRepository(TargetPlatformValidator.java:807)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractDeclarativeValidator$MethodWrapper.invoke(AbstractDeclarativeValidator.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractDeclarativeValidator.internalValidate(AbstractDeclarativeValidator.java:312)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractInjectableValidator.validate(AbstractInjectableValidator.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.CompositeEValidator.validate(CompositeEValidator.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.doValidate(Diagnostician.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:158)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.doValidateContents(Diagnostician.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:161)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.doValidateContents(Diagnostician.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:161)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter$CustomDiagnostician.validate(Converter.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician.validate(Diagnostician.java:108)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter.doGenerateTargetDefinitionFile(Converter.java:106)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.Converter.generateTargetDefinitionFile(Converter.java:74)
        at fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform.pde.ConverterApplication.start(ConverterApplication.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2017-01-16 10:05:21.364
        !MESSAGE Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/content.xml
        !STACK 0
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
        [ERROR]   Unable to read repository at http://www-artifactory:8081/artifactory/eclipse-mars-releases/.
        Problems occurred during generation of target platform definition file.
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 34:02 min
        [INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-16T10:05:22+01:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/411M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-eclipserun-plugin:0.25.0:eclipse-run (default) on project target-definition-dsl-example: Error while executing platform: Error while executing platform (return code: -1) -> [Help 1]
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptionat
```

compositeContent.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?compositeMetadataRepository version='1.0.0'?>
<repository name='Eclipse Mars repository' type='org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository' version='1.0.0'>
    <properties size='3'>
        <property name='p2.timestamp' value='1313779613760'/>
        <property name='p2.atomic.composite.loading' value='true'/>
    </properties>
    <children size='4'>
        <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/'/>
        <child location='201506241002' />
        <child location='201510021000' />
        <child location='201602261000' />
    </children>    
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achive it is to create a virtual repository in artifactory and enter `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/` as remote URL. You can then use the virtual repository URL in your tycho configuration. This will create a new remote repository for `download.eclipse.org` under the hood but you won't need to use the remote repository.

See [artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/P2+Repositories#P2Repositories-DefiningaVirtualRepository) for further info.

Comment: Using a virtual repository has the same result.

Comment: @SandraParsick, it probably doesn't work because you already have incorrect remote repositories (that points on eclipse) configured and you need to delete them before. The right way to work with P2 and Artifactory is to create Virtual repository, put the relevant remote repository URL/s inside the 'P2 Repository URL' field and let Artifactory to create the remote repository for you. Also, the resolution should be done through the virtual repository, and not directly through the remote repository. More info can be found here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/P2+Repositories

Comment: @Shayb I setup a virtual repository like it is described in the wiki and I get the same error message in my build. I wil open in bug in artifactory's jira.

Comment: @SandraParsick. Did you get any feedback about this problem from JFrog?

Comment: @JoaquinMorcate No, unfortunately not. My workaround is that I downloaded the whole external p2 repository and I host it as by myself. A really fishy solution.